# Does DOMContentLoaded wait for web fonts (Firefox)?

Tags: javascript, webfonts, google-webfonts, domcontentloaded

I'm using Google's web fonts in an application and I noticed that `DOMContentLoaded` doesn't seem to fire in Firefox until after the web font is downloaded. Am I doing something wrong or is this expected behavior?

My font is included with something like this placed in the `head` section:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
```

My JavaScript is linked at the bottom of my page with an event added like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  ...do stuff...
})
```

I tried testing this on Chrome but couldn't really determine which order it happened (the font loaded so fast).

Answer (score 2):

NO, it does NOT!

tested in Chrome and Firefox. which is a silly thing, as custom fonts may change dimensions of the layout, so you have to apply some tricks.. to make it pixel perfect.

The simpliest way to bypass this (initialization pitfails with size/position detection, like getBoundingClientRect() etc.) with modern browsers is to do:

```
window.addEventListener('load', /* do things here */)
```

..or, another way is to put, for example:

```
<link rel="preload" href="fonts/Oxygen.woff2" as="font">
```

inside the head (it's called browser preload hints).

Comment: Could just use `window.addEventListener('load', /* do things here */)` to bypass this. The time that the question was asked it appears that the answer was yes, which is interesting but also makes sense to change because a font is not technically part of the DOM

Answer (score 1):

According to Mozilla's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) on `DOMContentLoaded`:

> Note: Stylesheet loads block script execution, so if you have a `<script>` after a `<link rel="stylesheet" ...>`, the page will not finish parsing - and `DOMContentLoaded` will not fire - until the stylesheet is loaded.

Thus, it appears that you are experiencing the expected behavior such that `DOMContentLoaded` is not fired until after your external web font is fully downloaded.

Comment: Is there any workaround? I am trying to attach some behavior to my page. On slow connections my page appears unresponsive until the font load. The only solution I see is 1) Don't use DOMContentLoaded 2) put the JS at the bottom of the HTML file so the DOM nodes are available and just execute the JS directly (i.e not in a callback) 3) put the stylesheets after the JS to prevent blocking

Is there a better way or is that the best?

Comment: In terms of the modularity and readability of your code, your third option (loading the stylesheets after your JS to prevent blocking) seems like the best way to accomplish the behavior that you described.